# Sharing and security missing in Windows XP

Tags: windows, file-sharing

["Sharing and Security" is missing from my XP Laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/56417/sharing-and-security-is-missing-from-my-xp-laptop) ..

according to the topic at link above, i would like to ask you about this problem.  I already check the "use simple file sharing" as picture you shown, but the sharing and security is still not appear.  What is the problem exactly?

Comment: What are you trying to share?

You can try `Shift-Right-Click`

Answer (score 3):

The topic you link to actually says to *disable* (not *enable*) that option. Also, are you using XP Pro or a "limited" version?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have partition formatted as NTFS?